# Approximate sparse linear solve

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear system $Ax=b$ that I need to solve many times with the same $A$ but slightly different $b$. $A$ is large, sparse, and SPD. Since this is for 3D rendering software, error requirements are not very strict (relative error around $.01$ to $0.1$ is fine). However the step to process each $b$ must be very fast, and not use much memory.

Is there a decomposition or iterative method I can use where I can trade off accuracy for sparsity (and thus speed)?

Conjugate gradient seems promising, but it requires keeping $A$ around. Is there some pre-processing step I can do on $A$ to increase its sparsity?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explore the larger realm of [krylov subspace methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace). Generally speaking, the smaller the subspace the worse the approximation to the solution of $Ax=b$, though methods such as GMRES often produce quite surprisingly accurate results with only a few iterations.

Comment: I looked into this, and I'm not sure how I could precalculate the krylov subspace, given that it depends on $r_0$ and thus $b$.